# Query an ISODate based on local timeDate

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to work something out which seems unfathomable. If transaction_date as listed below (which by the way is a string and I can't seem to get it to convert to an ISODate for love nor money) is in UTC time, how then can I query for a month range (if it was a date) and sum the sales?

What I don't want is a UTC month, I want local timezone month. So I guess my question is twofold,

1. Does anyone have any idea how to convert transaction_date into an ISODate instead of string? $DateFromString does not work
2. How do you do a query which is entered as intended local timezone where the transaction_date is stored as the UTC date?

Thanks, Matt

```
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ab485c669150d532c41769f"),
    "object_origin" : "vend",
    "company" : "5a9a73bb-0c5a-41db-8d06-76ac2d1e04b0",
    "connection" : "2f758916-2eb1-4d95-a3bb-7d6258bc2143",
    "object_creation_date" : ISODate("2018-03-16T10:40:20.875+13:00"),
    "transaction_date" : "2018-03-07T11:36:48",
    "transaction_gross_value" : 165,
    "transaction_net_value" : 137.5,
    "transaction_tax_value" : 27.5,
    "transaction_cost_value" : 80,
    "object_class" : "goods-service-transaction",
    "object_origin_category" : "point-of-sale",
    "object_type" : "receipt",
    "object_origin_type" : "offline",
    "transaction_reference" : "119",
    "transaction_status" : "CLOSED",
    "transaction_currency" : "GBP",
    "party_identifier" : "WALKIN",
    "staff_identifier" : "02dcd191-ae2b-11e6-f485-79681a952bd4",
    "staff_name" : "uat2@9spokes.com",
    "line_items" : [
        {
            "item_name" : "Dress Shirt / Polyester / Large",
            "item_system_id" : "5051599d-40c2-a66a-11e8-21fbce105df0",
            "item_identifier" : "10024",
            "item_category" : "sales-revenue",
            "item_quantity" : 1,
            "item_net_unit_sale_value" : 62.5,
            "item_net_unit_discount_value" : 0,
            "item_net_unit_member_value" : 0,
            "item_net_unit_cost_value" : 60,
            "item_unit_tax_value" : 12.5,
            "item_price_list_reference" : 0,
            "item_total_sale_value" : 62.5,
            "item_total_tax_value" : 12.5
        },
        {
            "item_name" : "Dress Shirt / Cotton / Large",
            "item_system_id" : "5051599d-40c2-a66a-11e8-21fbd07bb8a4",
            "item_identifier" : "10021",
            "item_category" : "sales-revenue",
            "item_quantity" : 1,
            "item_net_unit_sale_value" : 75,
            "item_net_unit_discount_value" : 0,
            "item_net_unit_member_value" : 0,
            "item_net_unit_cost_value" : 20,
            "item_unit_tax_value" : 15,
            "item_price_list_reference" : 0,
            "item_total_sale_value" : 75,
            "item_total_tax_value" : 15
        }
    ]
    }
```

Comment: so, upgrade to Mongo 3.6 so date sorted however, still this never ending cycle of cluster which is local time vs UTC. If I need to compare global values, I need a local time context for companies anywhere in the world. Is it viable to store local time to use for lookup purposes and how might a script that delivers that look?

Answer (score 1):

With MongoDB 3.6, you can use **`$dateFromString`** and set a timezone. This will return an `ISODate()` that you can query with **`$gt`** or **`$lt`**:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "transaction_date": {
            "$dateFromString": {
                "dateString": "$transaction_date",
                "timezone": "America/New_York"
            }
        }
    }
}])
```

This will return

```
{
  "_id": ObjectId("5ab485c669150d532c41769f"),
  "transaction_date": ISODate("2018-03-07T16:36:48Z")
}
```

you can try it here: [mongoplayground.net/p/lfA33eBRx8p](https://mongoplayground.net/p/lfA33eBRx8p)

Comment: any idea about stating specific times and dates which are applicable in all timezones? Like, I want the count of sales for 1pm on Monday in every country - not transposed by timezone, but specifically 1pm. Thanks